# Jquery TimePicker : How to dynamically change Datepair end time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using a Jquery Timepicker .

I have two input fields - to Accept times.

I am using a Jquery UI timer as per documentation here - http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

for handle appointment date and time. these following code i create for user can select start time of appointment and end time default generate with 1 hours durations, but i need 30 min gap between start time and end time, how these possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Demos and Documentation</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

    <script src="lib/pikaday.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/pikaday.css" />

    <script src="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/site.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/site.css" />

    <script src="dist/datepair.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jquery.datepair.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="examples">
        <article>
            <div class="demo">
                <p id="basicExample">
                    <input type="text" class="date start" />
                    <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
                    <input type="text" class="time end" id="ggg"/>
                    <input type="text" class="date end" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <script>
                $('#basicExample .time').timepicker({
                    'showDuration': false,
                    'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
     'step': '60',
     'minTime': '9:00am',
     'maxTime': '7:00pm',
     'disableTimeRanges': [
      ['1pm', '3pm'],
     ]
    });
       $('#basicExample .date').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      weekStart: 1,
      daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
      autoclose: true
                });
    $('#basicExample .time').datepair();
                var basicExampleEl = document.getElementById('basicExample');
                var datepair = new Datepair(basicExampleEl);
            </script>
        </article> 
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a gap of half an hour, change

```
'step': '60',
```

to

```
'step': '30'
```

and if you want to add intervals of 30 mins to just the second drop down for end time, then add the following code snippet before your `$('#basicExample .date')` statement

```
               $('#basicExample .end').timepicker({
                    'showDuration': false,
                    'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
                    'step': '30',
                    'minTime': '9:00am',
                    'maxTime': '7:00pm',
                    'disableTimeRanges': [
                        ['1pm', '3pm'],
                    ]
                });
```

Comment: the start time is start from 1 hours and end time need 30 min gap after start time. i understand what you say.

Comment: you mean the start time drop down should show interval of 1 hr and end time drop down should show interval of 30 mins?

Comment: after add this code end time display 30 min difference but when user select start time, end time comes 1 hours gap. i don't hows to handle it, when user select start date,  end date come with 30 min difference auto.